# HQL syntax error

Tags: spring, hibernate

I debug for a long time, couldn't find why this HQL is not working:

```
   <sql-query name="getCampaignParameters">
    <![CDATA[ 
      from CampaignParameter cp 
      where cp.campaign = :campaign    
    ]]>
    <query-param name="campaign" type="com.bean.Campaign"/> 
   </sql-query>
```

It says: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from CampaignParameter cp 
      where cp.campaign = 1' at line 1

I didn't pass the 1, what could be wrong with this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the element is named `sql-query`. So it should contain a **SQL** query, not a **HQL** query.

If you want to define a **HQL** query, use `<query>`.

Or better, stop using XML files to define your mappings and queries.